# How do ultrafilters of subgroups look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, filters

In my work related to the axiom of choice one of the central notions is a filter of subgroups. Namely, if $G$ is a group, a filter of subgroups is a non-empty collection of subgroups which is closed under supergroups and finite intersections.

But we are not interested in any filter, but specifically in *normal* filters which satisfy the clause that if $g\in G$ and $H$ is in the filter, then $g Hg^{-1}$ is also in the filter.

Are there also ultrafilters (maximal proper filters) of subgroups? Certainly there are principal ones, e.g. all the groups which contain a certain element of $G$ is the principal ultrafilter generated by the subgroup $\langle g\rangle$. But are there *free* ultrafilters?

If there are, are there any normal ultrafilters (ultrafilters which are also normal), or do the two conditions clash in some way?

I know that we can think about the filters of subgroups as just filters on $G$ in the standard set theoretic sense, and then considering all the subgroups generated by sets in the filter. But this doesn't help me understand how might a free and normal ultrafilter of subgroups can look like, especially since this is not a bijection between the two notions (look at the case where a subgroup can be generated by two disjoint subsets).

Comment: To be honest, I'm not 100% sure how to tag this question.

Comment: Would the [tag:universal-algebra] tag be appropriate?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe. Topological group theory is also related somehow, since we can see these filters as "open subgroups", especially if the filter is normal.

Comment: How are you defining a *free* subgroup ultrafilter?

Comment: @user1729: Well, one which is not principal, I guess?

Comment: Okay. So finite index subgroups of residually finite groups might work. They always satisfy the intersection, supergroup and conjugation properties. The residual finiteness is there to ensure that there is no least element (without this assumption you can have least elements, e.g. consider $G=H\times F$ with $H$ infinite simple and $F$finite). The issue is the "ultra" bit...

Comment: @user1729: Indeed, one of the common cases is taking finitary permutations of the natural numbers (i.e. those that only move finitely many points). Being a limit of finite groups, the most natural filter is the one generated by groups which are the identity on an initial segment (a proper one, usually). And this is exactly the case you describe.

Comment: (Missing from my comment is that the topology of finite index subgroups of residually finite groups has a name ("the profinite topology") and has been studied lots.)

Comment: @user1729: Right, but a topology given from an ultrafilter is going to be a door space, rather than the profinite topology. Not to mention that in a lot of situation you'd have to move to the pro-${<}\kappa$ topology. Seeing how I'm not too familiar with the profinite topology to begin with...

Comment: Oh, my mistake, the profinite topology is all *normal* subgroups of finite index, which I guess will only be "ulta" if every subgroup of finite index is normal.

Comment: @user1729: Then I know even less than I thought on this topic. :)

Comment: You're not defining "ultrafilter" nor "normal ultrafilter". I think you forgot to assume that $\{1_G\}$ is not in any filter. Then it's reasonable to define an ultrafilter as a maximal filter. But even then I don't guess if you mean a maximal (normal filter), or an ultrafilter which is also a normal filter (I'm not sure these are equivalent notions), or if you mean something else.

Comment: By the way on the group $\mathbf{Z}$ the set of all nonzero subgroups is the unique ultrafilter, if I reconstituted the definition correctly.

Comment: @YCor: You're right, it's a subtlety I sort of ignored. Of course I had meant an ultrafilter which is normal. And by an ultrafilter, of course, I meant a maximal proper filter. Note that the improper filter (generated by the trivial group) is principal, by the way.

Comment: @YCor: You're also right about "all nontrivial subgroups of $\Bbb Z$" being a free normal ultrafilter. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think there are examples of "free ultrafilters" of subgroups which are normal, but I don't know, if this answers your question.

Consider the free commutative group $G = \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$ on $\mathbb{N}$ as the set of free generators. Then define a filter of subgroups

$$\mathcal{F} = \big\{H\subseteq G\,\big|\,\mbox{ there exists a cofinite subset }A\mbox{ of }\mathbb{N}\mbox{ such that }\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus A}\subseteq H\big\}$$

By Zorn's lemma there exists a maximal with respect to inclusion filter $\mathcal{U}$ of subgroups containing $\mathcal{F}$. It cannot be principal due to the fact that for every $g\in G$ there exists cofinite $A$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $g\not \in \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus A}$. On the other hand it is normal as $G$ is commutative.

Comment: Ah, of course, working with Abelian groups! Thanks. (It's not a complete answer to my quandary, but it is helpful.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am glad that you find it helpful. What would be a complete answer? Your question is interesting.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not 100% sure what would be a complete answer. But perhaps some general facts about ultrafilters of subgroups, rather than an example of a normal free ultrafilter... (The "usual" case sees $G$ as non-commutative, and with very few normal subgroups, although the Abelian cases do appear now and then.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah. I see. I agree it would be nice to have noncommutative example.